# I am working on a plugin and I have to use a method of one controller in another controller's method?

Tags: craft3, plugin-development

As I have a method name statistics() in my defaultController and I have to use the same method in viewController is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewController you can simply access your method like this:

```
public function actionDetails(){        
    $data = DefaultController::statistics();            
    return $data;
}
```

I hope this will help.

Thanks.